# Why is my rendered image darker that in viewport

Tags: rendering, hair

I'm trying to render my character but I only need hair so I render it as PNG I need transparent background but after rendering I get darker image. I tried 8/16 PNG/TIFF but same result. I set Color management in render to Standard. On left side render on right side viewport

[image]

https://mega.nz/file/FUpn2RSR#oDO5pNHQ43ipgt8HKmk9WfDOSTDng7QlP0IzvpEX2Bo

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem is that you are in the ***Material Preview*** mode in the viewport. If you go into your render shading in the viewport, you get the same results as your render:

[image]

To brighten this up, you could add lights and even your own HDRI environment in the **World Properties**. If you want to have the same thing as the Material Preview, you could just disable the Scene World here:

[image]